# Trying to Pass GITHUB_ENV value between Reusable Workflows ( Github Actions )

Tags: github-actions, cicd

I am trying to pass a value which is set in one job as GITHUB_ENV to the other which is actually a Reusable workflow.

The variable substitution is not happening for some reason, tried bunch of things,

The problem in question is '${FILENAME}', this is not getting replaced, tried with/without braces, single/double  quotes.

```
  manual:
    if: github.event_name != 'push'
    runs-on: binnacles
    steps:
    - name: Set Filename
      run: |
        echo "FILENAME=aws/${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}/${{ github.event.inputs.cluster_color }}/${{ github.event.inputs.region }}/${{ github.event.inputs.app_name }}.yaml" >> $GITHUB_ENV

  manual-deploy:
    if: github.event_name != 'push'
    needs: manual
    uses: ma/binnacles/.github/workflows/reuse.yaml@main
    with:
      file: '${FILENAME}'
    secrets:
      artifactory_username: ${{secrets.REGISTRY_USERNAME}}
      artifactory_password: ${{secrets.REGISTRY_PASSWORD}}
```

Expecting value set in FILENAME via $GITHUB_ENV to be passed on to the re usable job

Answer (score 0):

I will rather you try using outputs instead as i don't think environment variables are not passed between jobs, let alone reusable workflows.

What you could do is set the `FILENAME` as an output of the `manual` job then use the output in the `manual-deploy` job. Your workflow/jobs should resemble the below. You should also ensure that the reusable workflow at `ma/binnacles/.github/workflows/reuse.yaml` is expecting an input named file and uses it appropriately.

```yaml
manual:
  if: github.event_name != 'push'
  runs-on: binnacles
  steps:
    - name: Set Filename
      id: set_filename
      run: |
        echo "FILENAME=aws/${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}/${{ github.event.inputs.cluster_color }}/${{ github.event.inputs.region }}/${{ github.event.inputs.app_name }}.yaml"
        echo "::set-output name=filename::$FILENAME"

  outputs:
    filename: ${{ steps.set_filename.outputs.filename }}

manual-deploy:
  if: github.event_name != 'push'
  needs: manual
  uses: ma/binnacles/.github/workflows/reuse.yaml@main
  with:
    file: ${{ needs.manual.outputs.filename }}
  secrets:
    artifactory_username: ${{secrets.REGISTRY_USERNAME}}
    artifactory_password: ${{secrets.REGISTRY_PASSWORD}}
```